# Magento 2: Setup version for module is not specified

Tags: magento2, nginx, php-7, magento2-migration-tool, magento-enterprise-2

I was working on the Magento 2 CE, in which Data Migration Tool was already installed. I cleared the root folder and installed fresh Magento 2 EE in that folder. I also truncated the database of CE and import the fresh database of EE.

So at this point, everything is new and fresh. There is no third party module in it. But when I run the site, I get this weird error:

> Setup version for module 'Magento_DataMigrationTool' is not specified

I don't know what's wrong with it. Why is system thinking that I had installed Data Migration Tool? (Same-store is working fine in my local system.)

I then tried to place Data Migration Tool explicitly in `vendor/magento/` and inserted an entry in `setup_module` and `config.php` but I am still getting the same error.

(I am running Magento on nginx)

Comment: go to root directory of your magneto and type 
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

then your issue will be  resolved.

Comment: i did this several times but nothing happened.

Comment: give enough permission to DataMigrationTool directory 
and then run upgrade command again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ran the following command which fixed that issue:

> service php7-fpm reload

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try the following code. please go to root installation folder and fire following command

```
magento module:disable Magento_DataMigrationTool
```

Than clear cache , do re indexing and provide proper permission

Let me know if you have still any issue

Comment: output of command: Unknown module(s): 'Magento_DataMigrationTool'

Comment: Could you please make sure that it is not appear when you fire following command php bin/magento setup:upgrade just check it out

Comment: Also make sure that you need to do var and cache after this process

Comment: It does not appear in the list against upgrade command. I also cleared var and cache.